# Parsing with jquery a JSON string returned by a php script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hye.
I've this json string returned by a php script (2 different mysql queries on 2 different tables):
(sorry, that's a french application)

```
[{
  "statut":"2",
  "0":"2",
  "lib_statut":"En cours de traitement",
  "1":"En cours de traitement",
  "appelant":"GUEDIDER Jacqueline",
  "2":"GUEDIDER Jacqueline",
  "nom":"Virginie SORREL",
  "3":"Virginie SORREL",
  "date_creation":"05\/04\/2012 \u00e0 14:14:55",
  "4":"05\/04\/2012 \u00e0 14:14:55",
  "titre":"FACEO - Plus de message d'attente",
  "5":"FACEO - Plus de message d'attente"
},
{
  "nom":"Jonathan MORET",
  "0":"Jonathan MORET",
  "date_inter":"06\/04\/2012 \u00e0 11:18:07",
  "1":"06\/04\/2012 \u00e0 11:18:07"
},
{
  "nom":"Jonathan MORET",
  "0":"Jonathan MORET",
  "date_inter":"20\/04\/2012 \u00e0 08:22:53",
  "1":"20\/04\/2012 \u00e0 08:22:53"
}]
```

First Question: Does anybody knows why each row is recorded twice (first with an index, second with column name) ?

Second: How to parse both objects in my jquery script ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the queries that build it?  That probably has to do with why everything is twice.

Answer (score 1):

The reason everything appears twice, I confidently predict, is because the person who created that JSON did so by using the direct output of `mysql_fetch_array()` with no `$result_type` argument. This would also be true if using `mysqli_fetch_array()`/`mysqli_result::fetch_array()`.

Tell them (you?) to use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead.

In fact, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

If you do this, you don't need to worry about processing "both" objects because you will only have one.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, maybe because you use mysql_fetch_array (http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) without the second parameter (MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_BOTH, MYSQL_NUM)

Default is MYSQL_BOTH, and the function return an associative array with numeric key AND with the select param.

And for the second point, you can use

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

First Question: Does anybody knows why each row is recorded twice (first with an index, second with column name) ?

Maybe a wrong SQL Query ... ;) seriuously, without the table structure and the query it's not possible to say why ..;

Second: How to parse both objects in my jquery script ?

i assume that you have your JSON assigned to a Javacript var datas : here is how you can access your datas :

```
var datas = "yOURJSONSTRING"; // Replace here your json ...
// then
var firstEl = datas[0];
// Then you can use : 
console.log("Statut is : " +firstEl.statut); // consle is for debugging purpose on FF
// then for 2nd and 3rd elements: 
var sndEl = datas[1];
var trdtEl = datas[2];
```

Hope this will help ...

Regards;

mimiz